# Quartz Generator and exception handling

Tags: quartz-scheduler, mule

i have a flow that works as follows:

```
<flow name="ChatListener">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="eventTimer"
        repeatInterval="${chatListener.pollingInterval}">
        <quartz:event-generator-job />
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <filter ref="ActiveTrainingFilter" />

    <component>
        <singleton-object class="com.ChatListener.ChatListener" />
    </component>



    <not-filter>
        <payload-type-filter expectedType="org.mule.transport.NullPayload" />
    </not-filter>

    <collection-splitter />

    <vm:outbound-endpoint path="ChatMsgs"
        exchange-pattern="one-way" />
    <default-exception-strategy>
        <vm:outbound-endpoint path="ErrorMsgs"/>
    </default-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

Now, what is actually hapenning is that the generator calls the singleton compnent which does some DB retrieval and returns a collection of a java bean class which i later split (the null filter is in case i want to stop the flow).

My problem is - suppose i have an error connecting to the db and the component's oninitialise fails. What would keep the generator from trying to call the component over and over again? (and producing an error every time).

It looks to me as if i've handling something not quite right, So what would be the good to implement it to deal with exceptions?

Any ideas? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try the following:

- Declare the quartz endpoint in a global manner,
- Use it in the flow.
- Create a custom exception strategy and use it in the flow too.
- Inject the global quartz endpoint in this custom exception strategy.
- In this strategy, if the exception caught is one you deem characteristic to unrecoverable failure, call endpoint.stop().

You would need to go through JMX to restart the endpoint after clearing the error condition.

Comment: Okay, i'll probebly ask the same question on some of your other answers - but what does injecting an endpoing to the strategy actually mean?

Comment: I meant using Spring injection.